# XBAP won't run in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: wpf, xaml, firefox, xbap

I try to open a XAML Browser Application in Firefox, but it always displays an open/save dialog and for each option keeps opening a new tab.

Is there any solution?

Comment: The question is not very clear, what do you mean by xamp application or Xaml application as in your title?!

Comment: I think my question is clear enough. I have a xbap application, and i want to run it from an iframe in a aspx page, with mozilla firefox browser. When i do this, it will keep opening browser tabs and showing the open/save file dialog. Although directly from Visual Studio it will run it with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it seems that i have to copy the npwpf.dll file into the plugins folder of Mozilla.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox doesn't support XAML or XBAP applications. The only thing I'm aware of that does is Internet Explorer. Therefore, what you're seeing is expected behaviour. Firefox is treating them as a filetype it can't handle itself and downloading it.

Comment: Searching around i found that moving the npwpf.dll file into plugin folder of mozilla, will make things work. Is there in this action something illegal? I mean, am i allowed to do so?

Answer (score 4):

You need [WPF plug-in](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20enable%20and%20disable%20Windows%20Presentation%20Foundation) to run XBAP in Firefox.